# Disable Android's RecylerView scroll and fling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to implement a RecylerView that shows 1 CardView on the screen at a time and is controlled through two left and right arrow ImageButtons. I do not want to let the user scroll through the RecyclerView by themselves. How can I disable a RecylerView's scroll and fling features?

Here is where I initialize the View with a LinearLayoutManager

```
    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

    final RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_holder);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

And here is where I set up the left and right scroll buttons

```
  ImageButton rightClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rightClick);
  ImageButton leftClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftClick);


    rightClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if(position != recList.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
                markers[position + 1].showInfoWindow();
                GMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(result.get(position + 1).latlng, 17.0f));
                recList.smoothScrollToPosition(llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
            }
        }
    });

    leftClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if(position != 0) {
                GMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(result.get(llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1).latlng, 17.0f));
                recList.smoothScrollToPosition(llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution but this one work for me

> verticalRow.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

**//here verticalRow is recylerview object**

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the behavior that [AdapterViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper.html) offers
Excerpt from it below.

> Class Overview
>
> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.